# How to make web app that loads in the same way like flipkart or amazon?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js, performance, lazy-loading

Basically i want to know which technology or language these webapp uses?

**I want to achieve following:**

- Main content should load first and secondary content should loads in background after main content finished loading.
- Tertiary content should load only on scroll

What i know and **do not want to use** :

- Basic ajax call

  1. When main content load, fire ajax call for secondary content
  2. Fire ajax call for tertiary content when user scroll

> I am open to use any technologies

Comment: Pretty sure they use "basic" ajax calls... might be wrapped in a fancy wrapper, but essentially they're making "ajax" calls (maybe not jquery $.ajax and maybe websockets, but essentially it's all under the broader "ajax" term).

Comment: I agree! but @freedomn-m  its interesting how you place websockets under "ajax" term. :)

Comment: I can use other ways which use ajax implicitly but the point i don't want to fire ajax myself... just want to automate things a little

Comment: @Iceman yes, probably not worded the best :)

Comment: @RakeshSoni use react, angular... options are many. All have support for pagination, routing etc which will  abstract a lot of the things for you, so that you don't need to write vanilla ajax.